# Как перенести вторую строку с цифрами к верхней строке?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть вот такое содержимое в файле .txt:

```
https://url.html | Название товара | 

1356
```

Необходимо строку с числом перенести выше, то есть, чтобы было в итоге вот так:

```
https://url.html | Название товара | 1356
```

Как это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений?

Всего около 3000 строк в файле.

Comment: `[\r\n]+.*?(\d+)` с заменой на `\1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вызвать окно замены `cntr + h`

В найти:
`((?=[A-Za-z])[^\r\n]+)[\r\n]+(^[0-9]+$)`

В поле заменить на: `\1\2`

Первая группа `((?=[A-Za-z])[^\r\n]+)` ищем строку содержащую буквенные символы игнорируя символы переноса строки, `[\r\n]+` один или более символов переноса строки, вторая группа `(^[0-9]+$)` строка с цифрами от начала до конца строки.

Точками необходимо отметить регулярные выражения и снять галочку и новые строки